# How do I get the correct regex for this string?

Tags: python, regex, url

Here is some text that isn't working when I pass it as a parameter for description (including the return character and url following it).  I'm doing this in django.

> partner/BuzzFeed/fXkqhhIlOtA/NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia/The National Baseball Hall of Fame shows off 6 pieces of Yankees postseason memorabilia: a watch from the 1923 World Series; Babe Ruth's bat from the 1926 World Series; Yogi Berra's glove from Don Larsen's perfect game in 1956; the last out ball in the 1962 World Series; Derek Jeter's jersey from the 1996 World Series; Mariano Rivera's hat from the 2000 Subway Series. http://www.buzzfeed.com/sports/

```
urlpatterns = patterns('reserve.views',
    url(r'^partner/(?P<partner_name>[-\w]+)/$', 'partner_channel'),
    url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/$', 'video_player'),
    url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/(?P<title>.+)/(?P<desc>.+)/$', 'video_player'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$', 'all_partners'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

How do I change the regex for the desc parameter to allow this?

edit:

Request URL Page not found (404):

```
http:/localhost:8000/partner/BuzzFeed/fXkqhhIlOtA/NY%20Yankees:%206%20Essential%20Pieces%20of%20Postseason%20Memorabilia/The%20National%20Baseball%20Hall%20of%20Fame%20shows%20off%206%20pieces%20of%20Yankees%20postseason%20memorabilia:%20a%20watch%20from%20the%201923%20World%20Series;%20Babe%20Ruth's%20bat%20from%20the%201926%20World%20Series;%20Yogi%20Berra's%20glove%20from%20Don%20Larsen's%20perfect%20game%20in%201956;%20the%20last%20out%20ball%20in%20the%201962%20World%20Series;%20Derek%20Jeter's%20jersey%20from%20the%201996%20World%20Series;%20Mariano%20Rivera's%20hat%20from%20the%202000%20Subway%20Series.%0A%0Ahttp://www.buzzfeed.com/sports/
```

Comment: What description? What video?  Which author? I don't see any correlation between what you posted and what the regex does. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: How isn't it working.  And can you provide the entire text you are trying to parse.  Something is missing, as that regex can't possibly work with that text.  It doesn't start with 'partner'

Comment: I edited the url to show the full url now, not just what I believe is the problem (desc parameter).

Comment: Need more code. What you're showing isn't even a regex in Python, `url(r'text')` is showing a raw string literal of whatever `text` is, nothing in your example shows regex engine actually parsing.

Comment: More code! For starters, the rest of the `url` line that ends (for some reason) in a comma; the surrounding code before / after the `url` line, etc.

Comment: What appears before and after the original url line is the rest of the urls.py file (I'm doing this in django).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your title match is greedy and matches more than you want, and the / that is delimiting your sections is being included in the title, and the desc is everything after the last / (which is in the url)

Change it to be non-greedy `(?P<title>.+?)`

```
url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/(?P<title>.+?)/(?P<desc>.+)/$', 'video_player'),
```

Comment: I tried adding the "?" at the end of title but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work".  We can't help if you don't provide details.

Comment: Sorry...meaning I get the same error as before.  Page not found (404). The request URl is in the edit.

Comment: That is what the URL should be but I don't think it's matching the regex that was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Give it the `s` option. By default, `.` matches any character **except** newlines. Also, you need to make your title part non-greedy because otherwise it will match your whole description. Use `.+?` instead of `.+` to do so.

Comment: No, it's seperated by a `/` not a `:` (right after "Postseason Memorabilia/")

Answer (score 0):

Your `urlpatterns` is being overwritten (likely improperly). You have two patterns matching 'video_player' but none matching 'desc' :

```
url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/$', 'video_player'),
url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/(?P<title>.+)/(?P<desc>.+)/$', 'video_player'),
```

Change the last url identifier from above to something other than 'video_player'.